# What is the name of the Russian song in the season 3 episode 3?

Tags: house-of-cards

What is the name of the name of the Russian song the Russian president sang after the dinner in White House? What was the context and significance of the song?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Korobeiniki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Korobeiniki)**.

> "Korobeiniki" is a nineteenth-century Russian folk song that tells of a meeting between a peddler and a girl, in which they haggle over the price of goods in a veiled metaphor for courtship.

Comment: this sounds like the tetris theme song... is it?

Comment: Yes - it was used on Tetris

Comment: I'm assuming that the "courtship" was between the peddler and the girl, but could it also be a "veiled metaphor for courtship" between the Russian and U.S. Presidents?

Comment: Any idea what the significance of that song was in that scene?

Comment: See this meta post: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/questions/306/should-movie-trivia-questions-be-closed/1687#1687